# Android Browser disabling x scroll disables y scroll as well

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

I have a mobile web page on which I have disabled horizontal scrolling, as it interfered with some of the animations that I was doing. However, when I set `overflow-x:hidden` on html and body, android loses the ability to scroll vertically for some reason. iPad still seems to work away. I am on android 2.3 if it matters

Here is some sample code of the problem:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <style type="text/css">
        html,body {
            position:absolute;
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
            overflow-x:hidden;
        }

        .content span {
            white-space:nowrap;
            display:block;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
        <span>Really long line to force horizontal scrolling. Really long line to force horizontal scrolling. Really long line to force horizontal scrolling. Really long line to force horizontal scrolling. Really long line to force horizontal scrolling. Really long line to force horizontal scrolling. Really long line to force horizontal scrolling. Really long line to force horizontal scrolling.</span>

        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>7</span>
        <span>8</span>
        <span>9</span>

        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>7</span>
        <span>8</span>
        <span>9</span>

        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>7</span>
        <span>8</span>
        <span>9</span>

        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>7</span>
        <span>8</span>
        <span>9</span>

        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>7</span>
        <span>8</span>
        <span>9</span>

        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
        <span>4</span>
        <span>5</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>7</span>
        <span>8</span>
        <span>9</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m having a similar problem but from what i saw up to now what´s preventing the scroll is

```
height: 100%;
```

Try commenting that lien for Android 2.X and you´ll probably get it to scroll again.

Please let know if you find a way in which you can keep

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
```

And still scroll.

Thanks and good luck-